# Extracting specific strings/words from a list in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list in the following manner:

```
['0.089*"apple" + 0.089*"mango" + 0.089*"orange"','0.205*"apple" +0.167*"mango" + 0.167*"apple"','0.056*"orange" + 0.056*"apple" + 0.056*"orange"']
```

I would like to generate an output from the above list in the following manner

```
['apple mango orange','apple mango apple','orange apple orange']
```

I tried using regex but wasn't getting the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re 
lst = ['0.089*"apple" + 0.089*"mango" + 0.089*"orange"','0.205*"apple" +0.167*"mango" + 0.167*"apple"','0.056*"orange" + 0.056*"apple" + 0.056*"orange"']

result = [' '.join(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', s)) for s in lst]
```

output (`result`):

```
['apple mango orange', 'apple mango apple', 'orange apple orange']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.sub`

**Ex:**

```
import re
l = ['0.089*"apple" + 0.089*"mango" + 0.089*"orange"','0.205*"apple" +0.167*"mango" + 0.167*"apple"','0.056*"orange" + 0.056*"apple" + 0.056*"orange"']
for i in l:
    print( re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z\s]", "", i) )

res = [re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z\s]", "", i) for i in l] # ['apple  mango  orange', 'apple mango  apple', 'orange  apple  orange']
```

**Output:**

```
apple  mango  orange
apple mango  apple
orange  apple  orange
```

Comment: I had tried using re.findall to extract the words but wasn't getting the right output. Thanks Rakesh